# Separate box for electric water heater?

Tags: circuit-breaker

[image]
Do I need a separate electrical box for an electric water heater. I was told I needed a one so it's up to code as per the electrician? Changing from gas to electric I thought I could connect it to the circuit box that already there.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. What electric box is already there? Why do you think the electrician might be wrong? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the existing box?

Comment: Is your electrical panel close to and within sight of the water heater?

Comment: Normally you can.  Shoot us a picture of your old box. Also, does your power company have any rate incentives where they charge you less for the water heater's power?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your existing box but you would need a lockout device on the breaker so it can be locked in the off position. Because of cost many just put a disconnect at the heater. Just a note, in my area electric water heaters are much more expensive than gas to operate even compared to the electric heat pump style.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why does a water heater need a lockout device?

Comment: 422.30 / 31 requires a disconnecting means if not in site it needs to be lockable or meeting 110.25

Comment: I've read that you need a disconnect "in sight", so if you can see the breaker panel from the heater, you don't need a second disconnect.  Otherwise, you need a lockable breaker or a disconnect by the heater.  This seems to be what the comment from brhans was about.

Comment: @harper, it needs a lockout device for safety.  If you are servicing someone's water heater, do you want to bet your life that none of the people there, whom you've never met before, will not accidentally turn the breaker back on?

Comment: My WH doesn't have line of sight to the panel. I have my water heater on a wind-up style timer switch, which is right next to the water heater. The timer switch closes a 30A air conditioning relay when on.

Comment: @harper I believe your “switch” or contactor would meet the requirement for a disconnect as long as you can turn it off. Code requirements for it to be local and lockable if now within site.

Comment: Yes if someone was working on the water heater, you would have to say "Excuse me, get out of my way" to even access that timer switch.  It's an old style mechanical 2-wire timer switch [because it's a 240V circuit, after all; didn't have neutral for one of those modern timers], and it's in the box *above* the water heater wiring, so when the timer switch is off, it's off. And the relay switches both poles.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments. They were all very informative. I did need a lock out due to the WH being on the other side of the house. 